# Geo-spoofing (a desktop app for Debian specifically)?

Tags: android, linux, geo-location, debian

I want to spoof my location on my android device without jailbreaking.

I saw this [post](https://www.fonegeek.com/change-location/best-gps-location-spoofer-for-ios.html) about desktop software that can spoof mobile device via usb. Can you please help me find a free alternative that can be installed on a debain laptop?